# Nullpointer exception In Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to fetch id of rows if id is their is table.But After run the application getting null pointer exception at the line Cursor cursorc = sqdb.rawQuery(strQue, null);. Can someone help me please how to solve this.

Here is log cat.

```
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.explistview.Test_Demo.previousQuestionCalled(Test_Demo.java:254)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.explistview.Test_Demo$1.onClick(Test_Demo.java:102)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-13 16:34:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is Activity code.

```
 button_Previouse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    previousQuestionCalled(v);
                }
            });


            button_Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    nextQuestionCalled(v);
                }
            });

public void previousQuestionCalled(View view)
    {

        if (StaticClass.QuestionNumber > 0)
        {
            if (!StaticClass.isTest)
            {
                StaticClass.QuestionNumber = -1 + StaticClass.QuestionNumber;
                reHitting2();

                for(i=1 ; i <= vector_Size; i++)
                {
                    String strQue = "select count(question_id) from question_answers where question_id =" + 'i';
                    System.out.println(" i = " + i);

                    Cursor cursorc = sqdb.rawQuery(strQue, null);


                    if (cursorc.moveToFirst())
                    { 
                          int str_id = cursorc.getInt(cursorc.getColumnIndex("question_id"));
                          System.out.println("str_id = " + str_id);
                    }
                }

                if(i > 0)
                {
                    String strUpdateQuery = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change the code

```
String strQue = "select count(question_id) from question_answers where question_id =" + 'i';
```

to

```
String strQue = "select count(question_id) from question_answers where question_id =" + i;
```

if your column question_id is of integer type

otherwise

```
String strQue = "select count(question_id) from question_answers where question_id =" + "'i'";
```

Comment: In my Table total id is 16 but in log cat shows id is 0.

Comment: yes....the query return table contain single column only and named as cout(question_id)..hence cursorc.getColumnIndex("question_id") is not recognized .... you have to use cursorc.getColumnIndex(0)

Comment: :- I have used your code line but still my question_id is printed 0. for(i= 0 ; i <= vector_Size; i++){String strQue = "select count(id) AS QID, option from question_answers where id =" + i;Cursor cursorc = sqdb.rawQuery(strQue, null);if (cursorc.moveToFirst()){int str_id=cursorc.getInt(cursorc.getColumnIndex("QID"));String str_Option = cursorc.getString(cursorc.getColumnIndex("option"));}cursorc.close();} and my out put is like thie all rows id is one and option is correct but id is not printed properly.str_id = 1,str_id = 1

Comment: i think you are going wrong on cursor part here... cursorc.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursorc.isAfterLast()) {
      int str_id=cursorc.getInt(cursorc.getColumnIndex("QID"));
      String str_Option = cursorc.getString(cursorc.getColumnIndex("option"));
      cursorc.moveToNext();
    }

Comment: I have try but right now its different error like 10-14 E/AndroidRuntime(745):android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3

Comment: try giving the index as integer type ... ie  int str_id=cursorc.getInt(cursorc.getColumnIndex(0)); String str_Option = cursorc.getString(cursorc.getColumnIndex(1));

Comment: When I use this line not str_id=cursorc.getInt(cursorc.getColumnIndex(0)); String str_Option = cursorc.getString(cursorc.getColumnIndex(1));It get only column name not fetch culumn values.

Comment: ok sorry.....  str_id=cursorc.getInt(0); String str_Option = cursorc.getString(1); that was the correction

Answer (score 1):

> getting null pointer exception at the line Cursor cursorc = sqdb.rawQuery(strQue, null);.

You haven't initialized your `sqdb` variable.

Assuming that you're using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, call `getReadbaleDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` on the helper to get an `SQLiteDatabase` reference you can assign to the `sqdb` variable.

> I got error ony one line on log cat of E/CursorWindow(512): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1

The column index is not valid. Change

```
cursorc.getColumnIndex("question_id")
```

to e.g.

```
0
```

to retrieve the first column in the cursor. Your `getColumnIndex("question_id")` returns `-1` because `count(question_id)` is not the same as `question_id`.

Comment: :I got error ony one line on log cat of E/CursorWindow(512): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1

Comment: The column index is not valid. Updated the answer.